# i cant read this xml file to my page. the function works, but xml is not read

Tags: javascript, xml

This is my javascript code.

```
function getXmlData(){
        var icode=document.getElementById("itemcodee").value;
        alert(icode);
        var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Define which file to open and
        // send the request.
        Connect.open("GET", "assets/itemdetail.xml", false);
        Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        Connect.send(null);
        // Place the response in an XML document.
        var TheDocument = Connect.responseXML;
        // Place the root node in an element.
        var items = TheDocument.childNodes[0];
        // Retrieve each item in turn.
        for (var i = 0; i < items.children.length; i++)
        {
            var item = items.children[i];
            if(item==icode)
            {
                // Access each of the data values.
                var code = item.getElementsByTagName("code");
                var name = item.getElementsByTagName("name");
                var stock = item.getElementsByTagName("stock");
                // print these values to corresponding field
                document.getElementById("itemnamee").value=name;
                document.getElementById("itemstock").value=stock;
                alert(code+'|'+name+'|'+stock)
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Sorry, Item Not Found. Please check the inventory');
            }
}
}
```

and here is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xml>
<item><code>1</code><name>Sample Item</name><stock>0</stock></item>
<item><code>3</code><name>ITEM</name><stock>205000</stock></item>
<item><code>4</code><name>ABHI UPDATED</name><stock>2201</stock></item>
<item><code>5</code><name>Item 5</name><stock>10</stock></item>
<item><code>6</code><name>item 6</name><stock>2130</stock></item>
<item><code>7</code><name>Soap</name><stock>100</stock></item>
<item><code>8</code><name>New Item</name><stock>1201</stock></item>
</xml>
```

when i enter a data(icode here) i want the script to read related data from this xml file and display it on corresponding texbox.
i'm stuck with this for a pretty long time. i have tried various solutions,but still no luck.

Comment: what do you mean by "XML is not read". At which step does it fail? Are you sure "var items" is not null? Do you have errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: nope.nothing is showing. what i mean is i'm not getting any output. i get the first alert message..after that nothing..

Comment: try alert(items) and alert(item)

Comment: i did and this what it shows:- [object Element]. it showed twice and then directly to else clause alert.

_var item = items.children[i];
  alert(item);
  alert(items);
  if(item==icode)
  {_

Comment: Item==Icode is comparing HTML element to value

Comment: oh..but icode contains the value which i need as output. so i'm comparing it with item and trying to display that corresponding node and child values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var item = items.children[i];
var theCode = item.getElementsByTagName("code").html;
if(theCode==icode)
{
...
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: i have tried the above code. _
  var item = items.children[i];
  var theCode = item.getElementsByTagName("code").value;
  alert(theCode);_
but alert message shows undefined as value. i think script has not read the value from the node or node values are not read at all. is there a problem with the current script?

Comment: What is item? Try item.outerHTML

Comment: according to script,item is <item> node of given xml,with child nodes as <code>,<name> and <stock>.